# Guardar Datos Fichero en objetos java

Tags: java, netbeans, scanner

necesito hacer lo siguiente para un trabajo clase, necesito leer un fichero y almacenarlo en objetos para despues crear un XML con JAXB, estoy un poco perdido con java y los ficheros. El fichero txt es el siguiente:

```
% 2019-09-21 15:27:14 agonzalez jramirez
La impresora no tiene tóner.
Urgente
% 2019-09-22 10:28:37 jramirez afernandez
No se ha entregado la documentación del expediente EXP324.
Normal
% 2019-09-22 16:28:45 smartinez jramirez
No quedan folios.
Normal
% 2019-09-23 11:03:05 smartinez lsuarez
El ordenador de recepción no funciona.
Urgente
% 2019-09-28 13:11:29 jramirez lsuarez
Mi portátil no puede acceder a la wifi.
Normal
```

Y necesito almacenarlo en los siguientes objetos al leer el archivo:

```
    File file = new File("incidencias.txt");

    Scanner scanner;
    try {

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String linea = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner delimitar = new Scanner(linea);         
            delimitar.useDelimiter("\\s*");
            Incidencia i= new Incidencia();
            i.setFechahora(delimitar.next());
            i.setOrigen(delimitar.next());
            i.setDestino(delimitar.next());
            i.setDetalle(delimitar.next());
            i.setTipo(delimitar.next());


        }

        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Despues necesito crear un fichero XML con jaxb.

```
        JAXBContext contexto = JAXBContext.newInstance(Incidencias.class);
        Marshaller m = contexto.createMarshaller();
        File f = new File("incidencias.xml");
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(incidencias, f);
```

No se muy bien como leerlo y separar las incidencias.